# Add select field options with time intervals in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have creatd a website for a restaurant delivery service using WordPress and WooCommerce.

Basically when the customer is
checking out, he/she can choose when they want the food to be delivered. I want the select box to contain time intervals of 15 mins
ranging from the current time until the close time.

The restaurant is open for deliveries between 11:30 to 22:00. The first option I
want is to be "As soon as possible", and then the next option is an hour later (rounded to nearest 15mins), and then 15 mins each time.
So basically something like this:

(Suppose current time is 13:55)

As soon as possible
15:00
15:15
15:30
15:45
...and so on until close time (23:00)

Here is what I have tried so far but it only displayed whole time range. What should I do to disable past hours?

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {


woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_time', array(
'type' => 'select',
'class' => array( 'wps-drop' ),
'label' => ( '<span class="gew-lz">Desired Delivery Time</span>'),
'options' => array(
'sofort' => 'As soon as possible',
'12:00' => '12:00',
'12:30' => '12:30',
'13:00' => '13:00',
'13:30' => '13:30',
'14:00' => '14:00',
'17:30' => '17:30',
'18:00' => '18:00',
'18:30' => '18:30',
'19:00' => '19:00',
'19:30' => '19:30',
'20:00' => '20:00',
'20:30' => '20:30',
'21:00' => '21:00',
'21:30' => '21:30',
'22:00' => '22:00',

)
),

$checkout->get_value( 'delivery_time' ));

}
```

---

All I want to disable/deactive all the past hours. When displaying on front end checkout page.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WordPress [current_time()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) function which retrieves the current time based on specified type.

From that point on you can further customize your code to suit your needs, so you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {       
    // Open and close time
    $open_time = strtotime('11:30');
    $close_time = strtotime('22:00');
    
    // Current time
    $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    
    // Closed
    if( $current_time > $close_time || $current_time <= $open_time ) {
        // Default value
        $options['closed'] = __( 'Closed', 'woocommerce');
    } else {
        // Default value
        $options[''] = __( 'As soon as possible', 'woocommerce');
        
        // As soon as possible
        $asa_possible = strtotime( '+1 hour', $current_time );
        
        // Round to next 15 minutes (15 * 60 seconds)
        $asa_possible = ceil( $asa_possible / ( 15 * 60 ) ) * ( 15 * 60);
        
        // Add a new option every 15 minutes
        while( $asa_possible <= $close_time && $asa_possible >= $open_time ) {
            $value = date( 'H:i', $asa_possible );
            $options[$value] = $value;
            
            // Add 15 minutes
            $asa_possible = strtotime( '+15 minutes', $asa_possible );
        }
    }

    // Add field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_time', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __('Desired delivery time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options'       => $options,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_time' ));
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_notes', 10, 1 );
```